# ILA error on Vivado

Tags: fpga, vivado

The question is very silly and I hope it is not too inappropriate. Configuring any Integrated Logic Analyzer on Vivado, it happens to me that the program does not create appropriate files and therefore the synthesis fails.

[image]

Files not created and errors are red ones in the figure.I'm sure the written code is right because on another pc runs, I do not know if there's anything to change in the settings. I hope someone experienced in vivado can give me some advice.

Comment: it looks like youve changed the rtl since you went through the debug menu, if you are in the position of asking this question

Comment: I did not understand where I was wrong?

Comment: Did you try right clicking on the ila IP and selecting generate output products?

Comment: I responded too quickly. why don't you do synth and then use the debug menu to get started if you dont have experience with this?